# Magnific Popup not working in small screen

Tags: html, angularjs, magnific-popup

I can use magnificPopup directive in html as attribute. It's working in browser but it's not working in mobile.

```
angular.module('App')
        .directive('magnificPopup', function () {
            'use strict';

            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.magnificPopup({
                        type: 'image'
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to install magnificpopup, write command in

```
bower install magnific-popup

{
  "name": "magnific-popup",
  "main": [
    "dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js",
    "dist/magnific-popup.css"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">=1.8.0"
  },
  "ignore": [
    "node_modules/",
    "components/",
    "website/",
    "libs/"
  ]
}
```